# Speeding Up NumPy Array Generation from SymPy Poly Expression

Tags: python, sympy

I have a multivariable polynomial expression that I would like to convert into a square `numpy` matrix:

```
import sympy

n = 225
x, C = sympy.symbols(f'x:{n+1}'), sympy.symbols('C')

expr = -1
for i in range(1, n+1):
    expression += x[i]
    
penalty = sympy.Poly(C*(expr)**2)
```

So, `C` is just some constant (e.g., `C=0.5`) and the `penalty` would be the expansion of:

[image]

Ultimately, what I am looking for is the corresponding `numpy` matrix that represents this expanded expression (minus/dropping the constant term).

Also, note that we assume:

[image]

In other words, all linear terms are equal to their squared equivalent (we'll see more of this below).

To provide a more concrete example, let's say `n=3` then the `penalty` will be:

[image]

And this expands to:

[image]

Due to the relationship/equality of linear term mentioned above, this further simplifies to:

[image]

And dropping the constant term, `C`, would allow us to represent the coefficients of this polynomial as a 3x3 matrix with the squared terms positioned along the diagonal and the cross terms along the off diagonals:

[image]

or its equivalent acceptable symmetric form:

[image]

And this is the 2D `numpy` array that I would like to generate but, unfortunately, when `n=225` this takes a long time and eventually causes Python to crash. Is there a more efficient approach that I can take for any `n` that is large (less than `1000`)?

Answer (score 0):

SymPy offers many ways to work with polynomials:

1. symbolic expressions.
2. the `Poly` class, which can use two different representations (but that's a long story...).
3. the ring domains.

Depending on the problem we are going to solve, one approach may be substantially better than the others. Here, with ring domains I'm able to generate the polynomial up to n=1000 in less than two minutes (on my machine). Here is how:

```py
import sympy
from sympy import *
import timeit

n = 1000
x, C = sympy.symbols(f'x:{n+1}'), sympy.symbols('C')

t1 = timeit.default_timer()
expr = -1
for i in range(1, n+1):
    expr += x[i]
poly_expr = C*expr**2

t2 = timeit.default_timer()
print("Step 1 [s]: ", t2 - t1)

# polynomial ring of symbolic coefficients
K = EX[x]
# polynomial built with a polynomial ring
p = K.from_sympy(poly_expr)
t3 = timeit.default_timer()
print("Step 2 [s]: ", t3 - t2)

# new "symbolic" polynomial
new_poly = K.to_sympy(p)

t4 = timeit.default_timer()
print("Step 3 [s]: ", t4 - t3)

# apply assumption xi=xi**2
pows = new_poly.find(Pow)
sd = {p: p.base for p in pows}
new_poly = new_poly.xreplace(sd)
t5 = timeit.default_timer()
print("Step 4 [s]: ", t5 - t4)

# out:
# Step 1 [s]:  1.1785079769997537
# Step 2 [s]:  78.12489726600052
# Step 3 [s]:  26.54897919799987
# Step 4 [s]:  6.294931798999642
```

As for the generation of the matrix, I believe you have already asked that question a few weeks ago and received the answer...

NOTE: it shouldn't matter in this case because the coefficients of the polynomial are small, but if you regularly works with polynomials you will benefit a lot from installing [gmpy2](https://pypi.org/project/gmpy2/).

Comment: You want a polynomial ring with domain ZZ rather than EX. In this case it needs to be `ZZ[x+(C,)]` if `C` is included but multiplying everything by `C` in this calculation is pointless so I would just skip that and use `ZZ[x]`. Also I would definitely convert `expr` to the ring *before* squaring. Converting back with `to_sympy` is both slow and unnecessary. Much better to work with `p` rather than `new_poly`.

Comment: how do you apply the assumption `xi**2=xi` with `PolyElement`?

Comment: There are lots of ways. Ultimately `p` is a dict so you can use e.g. `p.terms()` and do everything manually. Alternatively you can compute the remainder `p.rem([x0**2-x0,x1**2-x1,...])`.

Comment: So I used `q = p.to_dict().copy()` to make a copy of the dict and manipulated it to drop the constant term and square the linear terms (rather than converting squared terms to linear terms) but now it's unclear what the best path is to convert the `q` dict back into a `PolyElement` as I do not see a `K.from_dict()` or even a `p.from_dict`. Any suggestions on this step @OscarBenjamin?

Comment: You can use `K(d)` to convert the dict back to `PolyElement`.

Comment: Going back to my original problem, all of this works for producing the final `nxn` matrix (via `sympy.hessian()`). However, as mentioned, as `n` gets larger, it is taking around 5 seconds for `n=50`, 71 seconds for `n=100`, 405 seconds for `n=150`, and 37 minutes for n=225`. Maybe going the `sympy.hessian` route isn't the best solution. Is there a faster alternative?

Comment: Update: I simply rolled my own function by manipulating the dictionary, and filling the matrix one element at a time, and it was much, much faster.

Comment: However, now I can't seem to figure out how to substitute values in for `C` as the traditional `new_poly.subs({C: 1})` now errors out with `ValueError: expected a polynomial generator, an integer, a string or None, got {C: 1}`