# Using subs for PolyElement

Tags: python, sympy

After creating a `sympy` `PolyElement`:

```
# This is just a simple example
x, P = sympy.symbols('x:3'), sympy.symbols('P')
K = ZZ[x+(P,)]

model = K.from_sympy(P*(x[1]+x[2]))
```

I expected to be able to, say, substitute `P=1` into the `model`:

```
model.subs({P: 1})
```

or, according to the [basic substitution docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution):

```
model.subs(P, 1)
```

However, I encounter the following ValueError:

```
ValueError: expected a polynomial generator, an integer, a string or None, got {P: 1}
```

After digging around, I learned that I could do this:

```
model.subs(3, 1)
```

But this is far less convenient. Is there a way to substitute directly via `P` rather than needing to know the index of `P` within `K.ring.gens`?

Comment: `sympy.symbols(f'x:3')` Why is this an f-string?

Comment: Oops, that was typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subs` method is for ordinary SymPy symbolic expression trees referred to as `Expr` or `Basic` in SymPy. Most SymPy documentation describes how to work with these expression trees because that is what most SymPY users are expected to use.

When you convert to a domain like `ZZ[x,y]` you are not using expression trees but rather a specialised representation of a more restricted class of "symbolic expressions". In the case of `ZZ[x,y]` the elements of this domain are polynomials in `x` and `y` with integer coefficients. Their representation is what is generally known as a sparse polynomial representation. You can see what this representation looks like if you convert an element to a `dict`:

```
In [25]: model
Out[25]: x1*P + x2*P

In [26]: dict(model)
Out[26]: {(0, 1, 0, 1): mpz(1), (0, 0, 1, 1): mpz(1)}
```

None of the methods of `Expr` should be expected to apply when you are using the domain system. Instead each different domain has its own associated element type which has its own methods.

The higher level representation built on top of the domain system is `Poly` which is also distinct from `Expr` but is intended more for use by users. You can read more about the domain system and how the domains are used inside `Poly` here:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/domainsintro.html

I would recommend firstly to use `Poly` rather than using the domains directly if you are not familiar with the use of computational rings and fields.

To answer your direct question about how to "substitute" into a `PolyElement` the answer is that there is an `evaluate` method:

```
In [5]: x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z')

In [6]: R = ZZ[x,y,z]

In [7]: R
Out[7]: ZZ[x,y,z]

In [8]: p = R(x**2 + y + z)

In [9]: p
Out[9]: x**2 + y + z

In [10]: type(p)
Out[10]: sympy.polys.rings.PolyElement

In [11]: xR = R(x)

In [12]: p.evaluate(xR, 3)
Out[12]: y + z + 9
```

The method is called `evaluate` because this is like evaluating a function if the polynomial is thought of as a function of its generating symbols x, y and z. You need to convert the Expr symbol `x` to the ring representation `xR` when working with the domains like this. The domains do not generally support implicit conversions between different representations because they are designed to be efficient and implicit conversions typically slow things down.

A more user friendly way of doing this is to use `Poly` instead which will handle conversions for you:

```
In [13]: p = (x**2 + y + z).as_poly()

In [14]: p
Out[14]: Poly(x**2 + y + z, x, y, z, domain='ZZ')

In [15]: p.eval(x, 3)
Out[15]: Poly(y + z + 9, y, z, domain='ZZ')

In [16]: type(p)
Out[16]: sympy.polys.polytools.Poly
```

Alternatively you can just use `Expr` and the ordinary `subs` method.

Comment: Thank you! I will go over the introduction. In the ring case, I also see that one could simply do `p.subs(R(x), 1)`, which feels more intuitive even if it requires converting the `Expr` to a `ring` representation inline.

Comment: There seems to be an important benefit of using `p.evaluate(R(x), 1)` over `p.subs(R(x), 1)` that I have discovered. `p.evaluate(R(x), 1).ring.gens` will provide an updated `gens` of `(y, z)` while `p.subs(R(x), 1).ring.gens` will continue to show `(x, y, z)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `PolyElement` representing `P` with `K`:

```py
p_ring = K(P)
# model.evaluate(p_ring, 4)
model.subs(p_ring, 4)
# out: 4*x1 + 4*x2
```

**EDIT to satisfy comment:** As I mentioned [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77328167/speeding-up-numpy-array-generation-from-sympy-poly-expression), there are different ways to work with polynomials in SymPy. `PolyElement` and symbolic expressions are different and unrelated things. You started with `P*(x[1]+x[2])`: this is a symbolic expression, because it contains objects of type `Symbol`. Then, you converted that symbolic expression to a `PolyElement` with `model = K.from_sympy(P*(x[1]+x[2]))`: the symbols `P, x[1], x[2]` are converted to `PolyElement`s. Then, `model.subs(P, 4)` fails because `P` is a symbolic expression, while `model` is a `PolyElement`, constructed with other `PolyElement`s, which doesn't contain the symbol `P`.

You can also manually convert your symbols to `PolyElement` with:

```
p_ring = K(P)
print(p_ring, type(p_ring))
# out: P <class 'sympy.polys.rings.PolyElement'>
```

At this point, you can use `p_ring` to perform your substitution: `model.evaluate(p_ring, 4)` works because `models` contains `p_ring`.

Comment: Considering that `subs` is a method for the `PolyElement`, shouldn't I be able to do `model.subs({P: 1})` or, according to the [basic substitution docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution),  even `model.subs(P, 1)`? I'm not really trying to `evaluate` the function and my real expression is much more complex than this.

Comment: You can also use model.subs(p_ring, 4) and it works just the same.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing some conceptual understanding of how a `ring` works (or how `PolyElement`/`domains` work??). I had initially thought that defining `P` as a `sympy` symbol was sufficient for substituting values for it where ever I needed. I can see that `model.subs(p_ring, 4)` works but it's not at all obvious to me why doing `p_ring = K(P)` is even necessary and, furthermore, why `model.subs(P, 4)` should fail even though it matches the basic substitution documentation? Are you able to provide me with a clearer explanation or alternative reference source for how to think about this?

Comment: You might want to read the docs that introduce the domains: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/domainsintro.html

Comment: @slaw updated answer.

Comment: Thank you @Davide_sd. I really appreciate your willingness to help me learn and understand!